# Can keycloak JavaScript based policy calls remote REST API?

Tags: authorization, keycloak

Can I call remote REST API from keycloak's JavaScript based policy? I need this because the current version of keycloak does not support custom attributes for resources according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40218752/abac-with-keycloak-using-resource-attributes-in-policy). Thus I created a special server that contains all required metadata for making decisions about granting access to resources.

Answer (score 0):

1.You can make jar and copy it into modules dir. Make it like other modules, create module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5" name="io.geewit.keycloak.provider">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="keycloak-mock-module-1.0.0.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="sun.jdk"/>
        <module name="sun.scripting"/>
        <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-core"/>
        <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi"/>
        <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

2.You edit the "keycloak-services" module.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <module name="sun.scripting"/>
    <module name="io.geewit.keycloak.provider"/>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I alreay tested it in newst version 4.8.3.Final. I am sure it works fine